# Why I can't scroll this list (on firefox)? Seems it will drag my element

Tags: html, css

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/YTKtf/) :

## HTML

```
<div class="box-booking-item">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="box-booking-item-content">
        <span class="box-booking-tendina">
            <span id="tendina_128" class="box-booking-tendina-elemento">Field 1</span>
            <span id="tendina_147" class="box-booking-tendina-elemento">Field 2</span>
            <span id="tendina_149" class="box-booking-tendina-elemento">Field 3</span>
            <span id="tendina_151" class="box-booking-tendina-elemento">Field 4</span>
            <span id="tendina_152" class="box-booking-tendina-elemento">Field 5</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.box-booking-item
{
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
}

.box-booking-item-content
{
    width:100%;
    cursor:pointer;  
}
.box-booking-tendina
{
    display:block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height:80px;
}

.box-booking-tendina-elemento
{
    height:22px;
    display:block;
}
```

Try, on Firefox (I have the 12.0, but tried with 10.0 and 11.0, it's the same), to click on the scroll bar, and scroll to down/up (pressing the bar, not using the arrow up and down). It's like it "drags" the whole container div.

Why this behaviour? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove  `href="javascript:void(0);"` from your code

**UPDATE** : Do either the previous method or just attach `onmousedown="return false;"` to `a` tag

Comment: Iam not a professor ,I only provided this answers with hit and trial method:-)

Comment: I think I'll change `a` with `span` : an `a` without href it is not so correct...

Comment: Yeah. That menu will show after clicking that `a`. I usually use a because, on double click, it doesnt select the text (which I don't like).

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `href="javascript:void(0);"` from your code. Perhaps you should replace the anchor with a div?

**For the comments below.**

To stop text being selectable you can use CSS.

Include this code on the item you want to stop being selectable.

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Comment: I put the anchor because, on double click, it doesnt select the text. But yeah, if this is the trouble, I'll replace with a span!

Comment: @markzzz - to prevent text selection you can use [`user-select: none`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4407335/681807). Anchors that go no where are bad karma. You shouldn't be using them just to stop text being selected